# How to Filter process on mongodb from a specific OS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi want to make a search of the current process of mongo,
and I want to get only the procces that are done by a specific OS. By example windows.

Running the query below

```
db.aggregate( [
    { $currentOp : { allUsers: true, localOps: true } },
    { $match: {  shard : 'shard-1' }}
 ])
```

I got a big json result. I need to filter more properties

I know that the information of OS . I can get from the property `$client` from `command` propperty that has the `json` result:

```
"command": {

        "$client": {
            "driver": {
                "name": "nodejs",
                "version": "3.1.7-1"
            },
            "os": {
                "type": "Windows_NT",
                "name": "win32",
                "architecture": "x64",
                "version": "10.0.17763"
            },
            "platform": "Node.js v10.2.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.6",
            "application": {
                "name": "NoSQLBoosterV5_91046.417"
            },
        },
        "$configServerState": {
            "opTime": {
                "ts": Timestamp(1553006039,
                5),
                "t": NumberLong(4)
            }
        },
        "$db": "cache"
    }
```

How to filter by `os` and `type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example, straightforward additional filter should work.

```
db.aggregate( [
    { $currentOp : { allUsers: true, localOps: true } },
    { $match: {$and: [
         { shard : 'shard-1' },
         { "command.$client.os.type": "Windows_NT" }]
    }}
 ])
```

Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

use this $filter:

filters the items array to only include documents that have a price greater than or equal to 100

```
$filter: {
   input: "$items",
   as: "item",
   cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
}
```

and full example is :

```
db.sales.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$items",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Can read about this in: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/